# arduino mega 2560 wont show up anymore at al

Tags: arduino

i have a arduino mega 2560 with an atmega 16u2 chip and it always worked. yesterday i tryed to put it into all of my usb ports but it won't show up anywhere not in the arduino ide and neither in my device manager ports tab.
if anything is not clear please ask and i hope you guys could help me.
ps. it is a real arduino not a chinese reproduction

i already tried to reprogram the atmega 16u2 chip but becouse the arduino doesn't show up i can't interact with the chip

Comment: ill ad some more info maybe it wil help if i plug my 2560 into any of my usb ports the ports tab in the arduino ide stays grayed out